# What's the difference in these overloading of << operator

Tags: c++

So I'd like some clarification over overloading the print operator <<

now this is how I have learned to do it:

1) **ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vector& v1)**

in this example we've got some Vector class that holds 3 integers.

I saw somebody try this instead:

2) **ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,  Vector& v1)**

so the difference is v1 is just a reference and not a const reference. The compiler then couldn't print any Vector objects that weren't Lvalues for example he also overloaded the * operator to be able to do things such as v1 * 2, simple vector times a scalar.
for example :

**std::cout << v1 << std::end** - this works (v1 is a vector)
 **std::cout << v1 * 2 << std::end** - this does not work

However when we changed the signature to be by value:

3) **ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,  Vector v1)**

his print was able to work... and I'm left wondering why this all happened?

Why couldn't the compiler recognize overload (2) for v1 * 2 but why sending it by value to (3) did work

Comment: Because you can bind a temporary to a const reference. Taking a const reference of an rvalue extends it's lifetime, but taking a non-const reference does not.

Comment: (3) works because copy of temporary result of  v1 * 2 into parameter v1 of operator<<() is OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v1 * 2` would return a temporary, the second overload can't be used because non-const lvalue references don't bind to temporaries.

The third overload is used copying the value returned by `v1 * 2`

Comment: Alright thanks a lot.
Can I also ask why 

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Vector v1) 

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vector& v1)

Would be considered ambiguous by the compiler?

Comment: because both operator<<(ostream& os, Vector v1) and operator<<(ostream& os, const Vector& v1) accept lvalue